# Multiple scripts making rest calls interfering

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rest, unix

So I am running into a problem with unix scripts that use curl to make rest calls. I have one script, that runs two other scripts inside of it.

```
cat example.sh
FILE="file1.txt"
RECIP="wilfred@blamagam.com"
rm -f $FILE
./script1.sh > $FILE
mail -s "subject" $RECIP < $FILE

RECIP="bob@blamagam.com"
rm -f $FILE
./script2.sh > $FILE
mail -s "subject" $RECIP < $FILE
exit 0
```

Each script makes rest calls to the same service. It is my understanding that script1.sh should completely finish before script2.sh is ran, however that is not the case. In the logs for the rest service I see a rest call from the second script in the middle of the first one still executing. The second script then fails because of this (it does not get any data returned).

I am modifying this process so I am not the one who originally wrote it. I am not seeing any forked processes, or background processes at all and I have been banging my head against the wall.

I do know that script2.sh works. Whenever script1.sh takes under a minute script2.sh works just fine, but more often than not script1.sh takes over a min, causing the second script to fail.

This is ran by a cron, and the contents of the files are mailed out, so I cant just default to running them manually. Any suggestions for what to look into would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Here is a high pseudo code example

```
script1.sh

ITEMS=`/usr/bin/curl -m 10 -k -u userName:passWord -L https://server/rest-service/rest?where=clause=value;clause2=value2&sel=field 2>/dev/null | sed s/<\/\?Attribute[^>]*>/\n/g | grep -v '^<' | grep -v '^$' | sed 's/ //g'`
echo "\n Subject for these metrics"
echo "$ITEMS"
```

Both scripts have lots of entries like this. There are 2 or 3 for loops but they are simple and I do not see any background processes being called. Its a large script so I could only provide a snippet. Could the rest call into pipes be causing an issue?

Comment: Without seeing script 1 and 2 there is no chance we can help. It may be possible that the scripts fork new processes, etc, thus the script finishing, the process not... You could build in a security mechanism in script 1 and 2 to ensure the order in which they will be ran...

Comment: I added an example, I hope it helps. The script is just lots of entries like this. Could the '&' in the rest call be causing issues? Any tips at all would help. I do not think this is an easy do this answer, but any tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should enclose such strings in `""`

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*:
Just tested this on my system and it seems to work.

```
cat example.sh
FILE="file1.txt"
RECIP="wilfred@blamagam.com"
rm -f "$FILE"
(./script1.sh > "$FILE") &
procscript1=$!
wait "$procscript1"
mail -s "subject" "$RECIP" < "$FILE"

RECIP="bob@blamagam.com"
rm -f "$FILE"
(./script2.sh > "$FILE") &
procscript2=$!
wait "$procscript2"
mail -s "subject" "$RECIP" < "$FILE"
exit 0
```

- Put the script executions in the background with the `&`.
- Get the process id's for each script execution.
- Use the `wait` command to block until the execution is done.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try and see what turns up the next time the cron is called